# Resolving Partial Image Serving with Node.js Behind Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I wanted to share a solution to a problem I recently encountered, which took me four painful days to resolve. Hopefully, this post saves someone else the headache.

**Problem:**

I was using Node.js behind Nginx as a reverse proxy. When serving image files, I consistently encountered an issue where the images were only partially served before an "Error: aborted" message appeared, and the connection terminated prematurely. This resulted in partially loaded images being displayed on the client side.

Here's an example of how the images appeared:
[image: partial image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

Despite initial testing pointing to an Node.js issue, after extensive troubleshooting, I discovered that the root cause was related to Nginx's default proxy timeout and buffering settings. These settings were breaking each request into blocks of approximately 100,000 bytes, leading to incomplete image delivery.

**Solution:**

I eventually resolved the issue by adjusting the buffer and timeout settings in the Nginx configuration. Here are the specific settings that I changed complete with their values:

```
proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Adjusting these settings allowed for complete requests to be served without interruption, resulting in the full images being correctly delivered to the client.

[image: complete image recieved]

I hope this information helps anyone who might be facing similar issues with partial content delivery when using Node.js behind an Nginx reverse proxy. When I was searching for answers, I was unable to find any clear answers both here or on other forums, including using ChatGPT, so I'm sharing this with the community to hopefully make your journey a little smoother and save you the pain that this caused me.